# How to use RepairCost tag within testing commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I had answered [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/321482/186522) and ran into a problem tagging a dropped item.

The command I gave will tag a leather chestplate with a protection level 1 enchantment.  Here is the command:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add example {Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",tag:{ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}]}},OnGround:1b}
```

This works properly if the item is obtained using the command:

```
/give @p minecraft:leather_chestplate 1 0 {ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}]}
```

The problem is that if the chest plate is enchanted with a book at the anvil, it gives the item another tag of **[RepairCost](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Enchantments)** so the item has increased repair costs.  I attempted to add `RepairCost:1` to the command inside the tag brackets:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add example {Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",tag:{RepairCost:1,ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}]}},OnGround:1b}
```

Over at [this page](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/2405293-difference-between-1-and-1b-in-nbt-tags), I found:

> when you are testing for/giving a score depending on its tag you often need to specify that data type

I have never seen integers specified so I tried `RepairCost:1i`.  This did not work either.

Then over at [this page](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/3iih89/datatag_0b_1b_ect_meaning/) I found:

> "auto:1b" is read as a Byte tag, while "auto:1" is read as an Integer tag.
> byte:1b OR byte:true OR byte:false
> short:1s
> integer:1
> long:1l
> float:1f OR float:1.0f
> double:1.0 OR double:1.0d
> compound:{}
> list:["data","data"]
> intArray:[1,1,1]
> string:"text"

It seems, integer is the default if unspecified.

I even took a look at the item in my inventory using [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac):
[image: NBTExporer]

I ended up building a testfor command where I just guessed at different variations and different positions within the command:

```
testfor @p {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",tag:{ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}],RepairCost:1}}}
```

Nothing I have tried has worked.  Is there some way to include RepairCost in detection commands like this?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please tell us what you tried so far... No, I'm just kidding, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RepairCost` is an integer. *`id` and `lvl`*, on the other hand, are shorts. You don't even need to include `RepairCost` to properly detect naturally enchanted items, just make sure you use the correct types (and if you use the correct types when `/give`ing the items too, you can detect both of them).

```
tag:{ench:[{id:0s,lvl:1s}]}
```

Comment: How does this differentiate between naturally enchanted items and items that got enchanted with commands?

Comment: @Fabian It doesn't, and as I understand the question OP doesn't want to. He used `/give` to get an enchanted item, but unintentionally used the wrong data type. He made a command to test for the item, which worked, but then found out that it wouldn't detect naturally enchanted items. He thought the problem was that he'd left out `RepairCost`, but it was actually a type mismatch on `id` and `lvl`. That's my read anyway.

Comment: As I figured, I was over looking something simple.  You are absolutely correct.  The command works with or without the RepairCost when the correct data types are specified for enchantments.  I also opened my inventory with NBTExplorer to look at items obtained with give command and though the item has working protection 1, they are stored as integers.  Obtained at the anvil, they are shorts.  Thank you for expanding my knowledge on data types.  I will not be omitting them from commands any longer.